# MSI for multiple websites WITHOUT custom actions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I would like to create an installer that installs 6 websites, all of which rely on a data access library.  So the solution contains 6 web applications, and 1 class library.

Question is: how can I accomplish this without using custom actions?

So far, the only thing I've thought of is to make merge modules out of the web app projects, each of them throwing in the primary output of the class library project, and then making a main installer that has all the merge modules.

Comment: Why do you not want to use custom actions? Or do you mean you don't want to use custom actions to do 'X'?

Comment: Because the "Web Setup" project already does what needs to be done.  Instead of reimplementing the creation of virtual directories of a site chosen by the user in a custom action and scaling it to allow the user to choose multiple websites, maybe there's a way to do this whithout writing custom code

Answer (score 0):

I would put each website in a feature that way you could give the end user the control over which website they require, if that is an option.

Although, you'll have to repeat the same type of code for each website in their respective.wxs file.